# Derivative of a vector field's Jacobian matrix

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, jacobian

let $\phi :\mathbb{R^+\times R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3} $ defined as follows

for all $(t,X)\in\mathbb{R^+\times R^3}$ we have: $\phi(t,X)=(\phi_1(t,X),\phi_2(t,X),\phi_3(t,X))$. And we define the Jacobian Matrix of $\phi(t,.):$

$$
   J_t(X)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_3}} \\
   \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_3}}\\
   \frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_3}}\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$ 
And I want to prove that : $\partial_tJ_t(X)=div[\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t,X)]J(t,X)$
My idea:
$$
   \partial_tJ_t(X)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial {x_3}} \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial {x_3}}\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_1}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_2}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial \phi_3}{\partial {x_3}}\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$ 
But it did not work.

Comment: You may have confused the Jacobian matrix with the Jacobian (determinant), or there may be smthg missing in OP...
Is $J$ the same thing as $J_t$ in the proposed formula?
Why is $J_t$ only a function of $X$ (and not of $(t,X)$)?

Comment: It is the determiniant and $J$ is $J(t,x)$

Comment: OK, you maybe rather mean $J(t,X)$. But do we have $J = J_t = \det [\partial \phi / \partial X]$? Please edit your post to avoid confusion